# Error registering Android subscription with Google's ClassyTaxiJava sample app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to set up Android subcription using the ClassyTaxiJava example provided by Google.

When I add a new subscription on the Android app, I get an error in LogCat as follows:

E/ServerImpl: Invalid SKU or purchase token during registration

When I looked at the error in the Firebase Cloud Functions, I found the following:

*Unexpected error when querying Google Play Developer API. Please check if you use a correct service account*

*The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.*

See screenshot below:

[image]

I have tried giving my service account Owner permission, but it doesn't make any difference. I have also tried waiting for a few hours to no avail. I have also granted my service account permission on Google Play.

What am I missing?

Comment: subscription_register finished with status code: 404 in above figure. is that 404 is error code? I'm having the same problem with content_basic and content_premium. it's end with status code: 403 and Android app failed to loading the content for basic and premium subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting the old service account user, creating a new one and giving it Finance permission on Google Play console. I gave the service account Owner permission on GCP. Also, I added a new subscription.

Comment: After updating the scope, try updating any in-app or subscription item, no need to wait for 24 hours.